# How to put colour legend into plot in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot, legend

I am drawing a picture in Matlab as follows. I have tried many ways to put nice colour legend at the end of the picture, each colour represents a variable, e.g. 'inflation', 'interest rate', 'exchange rate' etc. The problem is I could not add them on correctly. My code of draw the graph is attached below.

I use command

```
fill
```

drawing the graphs, the data is a matrix (not provided in following codes, too big). Would any one teach me how to draw a colour legend at the bottom of the graph? Thanks!

[image]

```
%% Graph 1
z1 = squeeze(z(i_var(1),:,:));
xmin = x(1);
xmax = x(end);
ix = z1 > 0;
ymax = max(sum(z1.*ix));
ix = z1 < 0;
ymin = min(sum(z1.*ix));
if ymax-ymin < 1e-6
end

  figure('Name',endo_names(i_var(1),:)); 
subplot(2,1,1)
plot(x(2:end),z1(end,:),'k-','LineWidth',2)
hold on;
for i=1:gend
    i_1 = i-1;
    yp = 0;
    ym = 0;
    for k = 1:comp_nbr 
        zz = z1(k,i);
        if zz > 0
            fill([x(i) x(i) x(i+1) x(i+1)],[yp yp+zz yp+zz yp],k);
            yp = yp+zz;
        else
            fill([x(i) x(i) x(i+1) x(i+1)],[ym ym+zz ym+zz ym],k);
            ym = ym+zz;
        end
        hold on;
    end
end
plot(x(2:end),z1(end,:),'k-','LineWidth',2),
    set(gca,'xtick',[0 22 44 66 88 110]),
   set(gca,'xticklabel',{'1985q1', '1990q3', '1996q1', '2001q3', '2007q3',    '2013q1'}),title('Output gap')

axis([0 110 -3 3])
hold off;






%% Graph 2
z1 = squeeze(z(i_var(2),:,:));
xmin = x(1);
xmax = x(end);
ix = z1 > 0;
ymax = max(sum(z1.*ix));
ix = z1 < 0;
ymin = min(sum(z1.*ix));
if ymax-ymin < 1e-6
end

subplot(2,1,2)
plot(x(2:end),z1(end,:),'k-','LineWidth',2)
hold on;
for i=1:gend
    i_1 = i-1;
    yp = 0;
    ym = 0;
    for k = 1:comp_nbr 
        zz = z1(k,i);
        if zz > 0
            fill([x(i) x(i) x(i+1) x(i+1)],[yp yp+zz yp+zz yp],k);
            yp = yp+zz;
        else
            fill([x(i) x(i) x(i+1) x(i+1)],[ym ym+zz ym+zz ym],k);
            ym = ym+zz;
        end
        hold on;
    end
end
plot(x(2:end),z1(end,:),'k-','LineWidth',2),set(gca,'xtick',[0 22 44 66 88 110])  
set(gca,'xticklabel',{'1985q1', '1990q3', '1996q1', '2001q3', '2007q3', '2013q1'}), title('CPI inflation')

axis([0 110 -3 3])
hold off;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure `fill` has a way to use the traditional `legend`, so here's what I'd try: After each graph create dummy plots and use their colors to be the same as your `fill` objects and then use the regular legend:

```
hold on
L1 = plot(NaN,NaN,'r',NaN,NaN,'b',NaN,NaN,'y');
legend(L1,'inflation', 'interest rate' ,'exchange rate');
```

to set the location of the legend see the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/legend.html), for example:

```
  legend(L1,'inflation', 'interest rate' ,'exchange rate','Location','SouthOutside','Orientation','horizontal');
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use command: **colorbar**, for your purpose.
That command allows with some input parameters to choose which color is represented with adequate word. Try it.